# Accessing "inside" $scope without $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I have this controller, with $scope.go that I trigger with a simple ng-click and a string representing the name of my .json file. I then go to another view and use that .json file :

HTML

```
<tr class='clickableRow' ng-click="go('kanji')">
```

Controller

```
.controller('Api_docCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $state, $rootScope) {
$scope.go = function (json) {
  $state.go('api_doc_detail');
  $http.get('views/api_doc/' + json + '.json').success(function (data) {
    $rootScope.doc = (data)
    $rootScope.example = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
  })
};
```

});

Since I heard I shouldn't pollute $rootScape, I was wondering if there is another simple way of achieving the same result.

Comment: Typically you just want a service or a factory to encapsulate the calls to your http or RESTful services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a service

```
.factory('JsonService',function(){
           return {doc:null,example:null};
})
.controller('Api_docCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $state, JsonService) {
            $scope.go = function (json) {
            $state.go('api_doc_detail');
            $http.get('views/api_doc/' + json + '.json').success(function (data) {
            JsonService.doc = (data)
            JsonService.example = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
    })
};
```

Comment: Had to move the change of state after the call to the json file and it works great.